# Validaciones Regex Java

Tags: java, regex

tengo la siguiente expresión regular

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$
```

La cual valida que la expresión tenga  mayúsculas, minúsculas y números,

Lo que no eh podido agregar son signos especiales opcionales intente con

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]?[.]{8,}$
```

en teoría el `?` debería ser opcional, soy bastante nuevo con este de regex, agradezco cualquier ayuda

Comment: Hola Bruno, deseas validar que sean mayúsculas y sin caracteres especiales?

Comment: Necesita ser minimo 8 caracteres, con almenos una mayuscula - numero y con signos especiales por ej " - .  @"

Comment: Igual podrías poner intervalos de rango unicode para definir rangos más amplios de caracteres unicode

Comment: Gracias por tomarte tu tiempo Eduardo, en mi caso especifico solo son un puñado de signos especiales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para validar mínimo ocho caracteres con al menos una letra mayúscula y carácter especial puedes usar :

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$
```

Puedes usar https://www.regextester.com/ para realizar la validación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Si deseas que los caracteres especiales sean opcionales simplemente elimina esta parte: (?=.*[@$!%*?&]) del REGEX anterior y quedaría de esta forma:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el unico detalle que le veo es que los signos especiales no son opcionales, como se podria lograr??

Comment: actualicé mi respuesta Bruno.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @Jorgesys funciona de 10, voy a intentar entender estas magias

Comment: Excelente Bruno te sugiero revisar el enlace que comparte otristan94 http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/utiles/regex-diacriticos.php @BrunoSosaFastTag

Answer (score 1):

No soy muy bueno con Regex También soy principiante pero espero esto funcione

```
^(?=(?:.*\d){1})(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){1})(?=(?:.*[a-z]){1})(?=(?:.*[@$?¡\-_]){1})\S{8,16}$
```

Revisa esta pagina también te puede ayudar (espero a ver sido de utilidad)

[Regex Una Introduccion](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/utiles/regex-diacriticos.php)